# thread 1 :breakpoint7.1 to covert nsstring to int

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, int

This code  seems working but it's not

```
- (IBAction)caculate:(UIButton *)sender {

int x , h;
double y , p;

x = [textDegree.text intValue ] ;

{
if ((x >= 60 ) && (x < 65)) {

    y = 1;
} else if (( x >= 66) && (x <  70 )) {

    y =1.50;
} else if (( x >= 70) && (x <  75 )) {

    y = 2;
} else if (( x >= 75) && (x <  80 )) {

    y = 2.50 ;
} else if (( x >= 80) && (x <  85 )) {

    y = 3 ;
} else if (( x >= 85) && (x <  90 )) {

    y = 3.50 ;
} else if (( x >= 90) && (x <  95 )) {

    y = 3.75 ;
} else if (( x >= 95) && (x <=  100 )) {

    y = 4 ;
} else
    y = 0 ;
}


h = [textHour.text intValue];

p = y * h ;

point.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", p];
}
```

when I simulate it, it take me out and says

```
x = [textDegree.text intValue ] ;

thread 1 :breakpoint7.1
```

Comment: Sorry but is not so clear your problem... can you explain better? What did you expect from your code?

Comment: Do you know, what "break point" means?

Comment: @Lorenzo my code to calculate gpa for one class

Comment: Yes I know what is a breakpoint! It was not clear if is a your breakpoint or a crash...  What is the value of the text box?

Comment: @Lorenzo just numbers  one textfield for Degree and other for Credit Hours and the results show in label

Comment: Have the textbox a simple number or number with symbol like °C,°F, "," ?

Comment: @Lorenzo simple number

Comment: Try to use NSString *testString = textDegree.text; What is the result ? What do you have in the testString?

Comment: @Lorenzo its a seem get breakpoint

Comment: Are you sure your ViewController in the InterfaceBuilder has the correct class or if your textfiled is connected to your IBOutlet?

Comment: @Lorenzo i try it in my iPhone and it work great but in simulator is not

Comment: What Xcode version are you using?

Comment: @Lorenzo Version 6.3.2

Comment: Have you tried to clean all project and rebuild?

Comment: @Lorenzo no i will try it is their easy way or i should clean it one by one ?

Comment: From project menu' use clean and then build. If the problem persist (is strange) I suggest to create another project (from zero) and use the same code to see if this time it works and than check for difference. Can you post a screenshot of the xcode when you have the issue?